# Setting action directly on a Ember.View

Tags: ember.js

Is there a way to set action directly when defining a view without using the action helper?
My view is already a link so I can't use a template with it. I would need to use the click event but then my view must know my router.

Example:

```
App.Link = Em.View.extend({
    classNames: ['btn'],
    tagName: 'a',
    template: Em.Handlebars.compile("My Link"),
    click: function(event) {
        //I don't want to have to call this here
        App.router.doSomething();
    },
    //What Id like to do
    action: "doSomething"
})
```

Is this available anywhere? I couldn't find any information.

Comment: When trying to run out of the road, you generally encounter more problems... It applies to this case. You should use Ember as it is designed to work. Breaking the rules will result in broken design.

Answer (score 1):

You actually can do that via Bindings and it is pretty acceptable (at least from my point of view).  You end up using this quite a lot when dealing with a bunch of inner-connectivity between a lot of different view/objects.  It is actually one of the major reasons to use Ember (handles a lot of the bootstrapping for you).

```
    clickBinding: 'doSomething'
```

Made a [fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/scispear/rrtux/) so show a simple version it in action (mind you it can be a relative or absolute path).  They do also cover this in the [docs](http://emberjs.com/documentation/) if you are looking for more details.